# Adding repository via terminal results in "add-apt: command not found" error

Tags: 18.04, software-installation, sudo, repository

Every time I do anything I do anything related to `sudo` (mostly installing repositories), it says command not found.

I type:

```
sudo add apt-repository ppa:ppsspp/stable
```

It then says

```
sudo:add-apt: command not found
```

Sometimes it tells me to manually run `configure --a`, which I do, and it still doesn't work. Anyone know how to fix???

I'm on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of text. Instead [edit] your question to paste the text from your terminal.

Comment: Your question seems to have several typos, and your output looks like classic typo confusion. Your Ubuntu system is NOT forgiving of typographical errors. Double-check your typing before hitting <enter>. Pay close attention to mixing up spaces, dots, dashes, and underscores. That's common for new folks.

Comment: ...and when you include text from the terminal, **copy and paste** it instead of typing. Right now, the command in the question doesn't match the error message, which is a clear giveaway that the question doesn't contain accurate information for anyone trying to answer it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The command is `add-apt-repository`, you're missing the second hyphen.